# Checking if logging to website is successful via C#

Tags: c#

How can I check whether the login is successful, or failed, is it something with cookies?
Here's my code:

```
 const string baseurl = "http://maplestory.nexon.net/Default.aspx?PART=/Main";
    CookieContainer cookie;
    public Login(string user, string password)
    {

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseurl);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        string login = string.Format("userID={0}&password={1}&device_id={2}", user, password, "24275770-88e0-4e");
        byte[] postbuf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(login);
        req.ContentLength = postbuf.Length;
        Stream rs = req.GetRequestStream();
        rs.Write(postbuf, 0, postbuf.Length);
        rs.Close();
         cookie = req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

         WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
         resp.Close();

    }


}
```

I don't know if I really logged in. and BTW is there anything wrong with the current code?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your login logic, you usually send a cookie back in the response with some sort of token that you can check on each subsequent request.

So in your code, you'd create a authentication cookie and add it to your response:

```
resp.Cookies.Add(new Cookie("authCookie", "myToken"));
```

Take a look at how [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) works in ASP.NET, along with using a [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) to handle your authentication.  I'm not a huge fan of MembershipProvider, but it does provide a lot of basic authentication wiring with not a lot of effort (especially if you're cool with the default [AD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.aspx) or [SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx) providers for membership).

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE** If I wanted to check if a user is already logged in, I would need to check their Cookies collection and see if they have a valid authentication token/cookie.  If you use forms authentication, this is done for you.  If you don't have a valid cookie, you'll be redirected back to the login page.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, I'll be back in a while but I see that you're saying about ASP.NET and SQL and such, maybe you misunderstood me, I want to login a website via a program that I'm trying to create now.

Comment: Well, usually with an ASP.NET application, when you're logged in to the site, you'll get a cookie back from the server which you carry around and send up with each request.  So in your code above, you need to check if that cookie is there.  But there isn't just one way to do this - there are several ways.  Forms authentication has been around from the beginning of .net, and the membership provdiers give you some help with giving you a structure to validate authentication and let users login.